# WIF SAML RequestSecurityToken STS Internal server error

Tags: security, wif, saml

I try to reach my STS to request a token. The code is based on a blog post by @leastprivilege : [WCF and Identity in .NET 4.5: External Authentication with WS-Trust](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/11/16/wcf-and-identity-in-net-4-5-external-authentication-with-ws-trust/). I use the explicit approach (by code).

```
    private static SecurityToken RequestSecurityToken()
{
            // set up the ws-trust channel factory
            var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
                new UserNameWSTrustBinding(
                  SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
                  "https://federation.mydomain/adfs/services/trust/mex") { TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13 };

            //factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "user-pcote";
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "123456";

            // create token request
            var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
            {
                RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
                KeyType = KeyTypes.Symmetric,
                AppliesTo = new EndpointReference("https://myRP/")
            };

            var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
            return channel.Issue(rst);
        }
```

I can see the XML when copying the STS endpoint adress in my browser, therefore the federation server is reachable. But I always get an internal server error (500) as soon as I issue the token request. Does anybody have an idea what could be my problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally managed to get it working by changing the KeyType to KeyTypes.Bearer (since there's no certificate applied to the RP in AD FS). I based myseflf on this website that gives a good explanations on how it all relates :

http://blog.skadefro.dk/2011/09/claimsbased-authentication-and-wcf.html

> if we look in Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.KeyTypes we
>   see we can use Asymmetric, Symmetric or Bearer. Tons of post out there
>   about this.
>
> If you use Asymmetric you as requestor need to supply a key to encrypt
>   the claims with. ( set "UseKey” )
>
> If you use Symmetric the identity provider have all ready been told
>   what certificate to use, to encrypt the claims with.
>
> If you choose Bearer. The token get signed, but claims will not be
>   encrypted. If a token signing certificate have been assigned on the
>   Relying Party, claims will simply not be included at all.
>
> When you request a token, the token gets signed (not encrypted) with a
>   certificate installed on the Identity Provider ( ADFS ). If you add a
>   certificate on a Relying Party Trust (RP) on the ADFS server, the
>   claims inside the token gets encrypted with with that certificate.
>   Only host/applications that have access to the private key of that
>   certificate can now decrypt the token and read the claims. You don’t
>   need to read the claims in order to authenticate your self. For
>   instance if you have a WCF Service you want to call from within an
>   application. You can from within that application still request a
>   token from the ADFS server and then access the WCF service with that
>   Token. As long as the WCF service have access to the private key and
>   can read the claims, your application don’t need it.

```
private static SecurityToken RequestSecurityToken()
        {

            var binding = new UserNameWSTrustBinding(
                  SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);

            var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
                binding,
                new EndpointAddress(new Uri("<your_adfs_uri>/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed"), EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity("host/your.spn.com"))) { TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13 };

            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";

            // create token request
            var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
            {
                RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
                KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer,
                AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(<uri_of_your_relying_party>)
            };

            var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
            try
            {
                var response = channel.Issue(rst);
                return response ;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var message = e.Message;
                return null;
            }

        }
```

Comment: I have worked it out to have STS (both SAML 1.1 and 2.0), server and client up running and the C# source can be found here: https://github.com/tedyyu/WCF_Samples/tree/master/Non-MS-Sample/SAML

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the right endpoint (which was /adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed) but now I get the following error :

ID4007: The symmetric key inside the requested security token must be encrypted